# Mobile & Tablet Device Header Cut Off Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I am currently having a problem with the header & footer cut off on mobile devices (if viewed on mobile or tablet the header is not displayed full width across devices.) - Wordpress theme was designed on 2010 childs theme.

The URL is www.canonbody.com, here are the lines of code:

```
#colophon,#wrapper,.inner{width:1050px;min-width:1020px;}

header{width:100%;device-width:100%;min-width:100%;border-bottom:2pt solid #000;padding-bottom:17pt}

#footer #colophon{position:relative;height:292px}
#colophon{line-height:20px;padding-top:7px}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set `display:table` to the header, that fixed it for me.
But the gray background wont go to the edge, you can add `display: table` to it as well.

Also, firefox has `width: -moz-fit-content;` which does the trick, but it doesn't work in other browsers.